# Bridging two interfaces using NatD on OS X 10.6 (not working)

Tags: networking, osx-snow-leopard

I have an OS X 10.6 machine with two network cards:

```
1 - 10.1.10.2
2 - 192.168.1.2
```

and I'd like to forward all traffic coming in on port 192.168.1.2:4096 to another machine on the 10.* subnet (10.1.10.42). I've turned the firewall (ipfw) on and added basic rules:

```
00100 divert 8668 ip from any to any via en1 (en1 is the interface with the 192* addr)
00200 allow ip from any to any
65535 allow ip from any to an
```

and then run natd with:

```
sudo natd -v -l -a 192.168.1.2  en1 -dynamic -redirect_port tcp 10.1.10.42:3333 192.168.1.2:4096
```

Running in verbose mode this gives:

```
In  [TCP]  [TCP] my_remote_ip:50116 -> 192.168.1.2:4096 aliased to
           [TCP] my_remote_ip:50116 -> 10.1.10.42:3333
```

So natd is seeing the connection, and it thinks it's aliasing it, but the attempted connection (on the remote machine) always hangs and times out.

I've enabled IP Forwarding (`sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1`) and can't think of any other reason why this isn't working.

Any help would be appreciated.